# make query for filtering where object is in queryset

Tags: django, django-models

ive got three models

-Company

-Queue

-User

Company and Queue have a one to one relationship

User and Queue have a many to many relationship. Users can be in many queues, and more importantly, a queue can contain many users

How do I write a query that filters for companies whose queue contains a specified user? `joined_companies` should contain companies whose queues contain `user`

(`companies.queue.users` is a queryset of `User`s)

```py
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        
        companies = Company.objects.all()
        
        joined_companies = companies.filter(queue__users__contains=user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `contains`, you also do not need the first query, the scope of filter is all objects:

```
    user = request.user
    companies = models.Company.objects.filter(queue__users=user)
```

[`contains`](https://www.w3schools.com/django/ref_lookups_contains.php) lookup does not work, because you are looking for an `User` object instance instead of an value:

```
username = request.user.username
companies = models.Company.objects.filter(queue__users__username__contains=username)
```

Comment: Thanks this works, do you possibly have a link to the docs for searching for the presence of an object in a queryset like so... I can't seem to find it

Comment: At [many-to-many examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) under "lookups across relationships" and [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). There is a clear example in the first one.